# How use free space after lvremove

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, lvm

I have a server with multiple logical volumes. I deleted one, but I can not make use of the free space.

```
root@ubuntu:/tmp# lvs
  LV     VG     Attr   LSize Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  logs   system -wi-ao 6.48g                                      
  root   system -wi-ao 7.45g                                      
  swap_1 system -wi-ao 1.86g                                      
  var    system -wi-ao 6.52g
  server system -wi-ao 7.45g

root@ubuntu:/tmp# vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  system   1   4   0 wz--n- 29.76g 0
```

After deleting server logical volume, I can't use free space:

```
root@ubuntu:/tmp# vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  system   1   4   0 wz--n- 29.76g 7.45g

root@ubuntu:/tmp# lvextend -l 100%FREE /dev/system/root
  New size (1907 extents) matches existing size (1907 extents)
  Run `lvextend --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/system/root
```

Without the plus sign, you try to resize the LV to the free space instead of increasing it by it. In your case, this coincides with the current size.